# How does logic affect emotions?

Tags: emotion, emotional-intelligence

It is [seen](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4050437/#:%7E:text=Positive%20and%20negative%20emotion1,emotional%20content%20of%20the%20problem.) that logical reasoning of a human can be affected to a great extent by emotions. If you are feeling sad, you are more likely to reach a negative conclusion through logical reasoning than when you are feeling happy. So overall, it is clear that emotions affect logical reasoning. From what I've observed, logic appears to be an outcome of "desire". Desire is not quite considered an 'emotion' in psychology. It's understandable that desire result in existence of logic. The very existence of desire makes it so that one use logic to want to reach a logical conclusion.

Does logic affect emotion too? If so then which emotions does it affect or does it affect every emotion and to what extent? Is being more logical in "any" way an indication of being less emotional? Is it true that logical reasoning plays a role in controlling emotion making it so that adults who are logically much more capable than a child are better at it than a child, or does being able to control your emotion as an adult have no relation to being more logical?